# Vantagens/Desvantagens Magento x Opencart x Outro Open eCommerce

Tags: e-commerce, código-aberto

Estou com um projeto pra começar e eu gostaria de saber quais vantagens, desvantagens, recursos e etc. Ou seja, principais diferenças entre as plataformas e-commerce open source:

- Magento
- OpenCart
- Outros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As vantagens do **`Magento`** são inúmeras, incluindo praticamente ilimitado controle sobre a maneira que seu carrinho de compras irá parecer (design) e como o usuário irá interagir com ele. Excelente controle de SEO com as `friendly URLs` e você pode sempre utilizar tags.

Se você tem um baixo orçamento, o **`OpenCart`** pode ser a melhor escolha. O `OpenCart` é um sistema poderoso e indicado para start-ups. Mais fácil de manusear e gerenciar para usuários mais leigos do que o `Magento`. Requer menor investimento se comparado com o Magento (em relação à extensões de características como plugins, themes, etc).

`Magento` e `OpenCart` têm algumas vantagens parecidas:

- Ambos são plataformas `open souce`
- Ambos são populares e possuem grande comunidade de suporte
- Ambos são em PHP
- Ambos são plataformas eCommerce globais e suportam múltiplos idiomas e moedas
- Ambos são ricos em plugins e `resources`
- Ambos usam templates e podem ser mantidos por não programadores

O `OpenCart` é ótimo para começar "já vendendo", pois é mais tecnicamente mais simples.

**Veja a tabela abaixo extraída de um [site](http://itxdesign.com/) com os comparativos bem claros:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**E uso de mercado**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Outras plataformas**

Outras plataformas estão ganhando mercado, como é o caso do `Shopify`, `WooCommerce` e `PrestaShop`. Veja o principal diferencial de outras plataformas com relação ao [SEO](http://ecommerce-platforms.com/compare/best-ecommerce-platform-seo), por exemplo.

**Conclusão**

O `Magento` é mais completo, porém é mais complexo (consequentemente) e requer investimento financeiro maior (se utilizado da versão Pro e/ou se desejar estender suas características).

O `OpenCart` é mais simples, possui temas mais baratos bem como seus plugins, mas ainda continua sendo uma excelente escolha para qualquer tipo de comércio eletrônico. Seria indicado para start-up.